# the spectrum of the commutative ring with unity only contains zero

Tags: commutative-algebra

We all know that the spectrum of a field contains only zero, since the only proper ideal is $0$, and field is integral domain. Thus, I think at the converse. I wonder whether there exists an example that although the spectrum of the commutative ring with unity contains only zero, that ring is $NOT$ a field?

thanks a lot.

Comment: The spectrum cannot be zero, since it is not a number or a module. It is a one point space.

Comment: thanks, I rewrited.

Comment: What do you call the "spectrum" of a field ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I mean the set that collects all the prime ideals of a field. I think this is just the defintion in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. If $R$ is not a field, take any non invertible $0\ne x\in R$. This element generates a nonzero proper ideal:

$I=\{rx: r\in R\}$

and so belongs to some nonzero maximal (and in particular prime) ideal. So a nonzero prime ideal surely exists.

Answer (score 1):

Note: A commutative ring $R$ with unit is integral if and only if $\{0\}$ is a prime ideal or equivalently if and only if $\{0\}\in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$.

So the answer depends on whether you ask for all rings or just integral domains. That is:

An integral domain $R$ is a field if and only if $\operatorname{Spec}(R) = \{\{0\}\}$.

However, there are commutative rings with zero divisors, for which the spectrum is a one-point space. By the above the unique prime ideal will **not** be the zero ideal.

The general statement you might be searching for is the following: A *noetherian* ring has a singleton as its spectrum, if and only if it is an *Artinian local ring*.

Comment: Your last general statement is not true; it only holds under Noetherian hypotheses

Comment: Thanks, you are right.